# Find, Select and Copy multiples random cells VBA Macro

Tags: vba, excel, find

i'm having troubles with a Macro that i can't figure it out how to do it, i need a Macro that can scan trough a workbook, Find 3 values, "Data: ", "N°" and "Rodovia:", make a offset of 1 column from them and select that value, and paste it in another sheet like this:

Data:     | 10/03/2014

N°:       | L02.020.22C

Rodovida: | GO-020

So it must select "10/03/2014", "L02.020.22C" and "GO-020"

I can do it using find and Resize i know, but they are not in the same row or column, they are located in random rows and columns, thats the problem, i tried to use a Range().Select with multiples .Find().offset() inside but it didn't worked

After that i need it to do it with all the cases in the workbook, so i need it to give me that

Case1Data|Case1N°|Case1Rodovia

Case2Data|Case2N°|Case2Rodovia

Case3Data|Case3N°|Case3Rodovia

UPDATE, Code so far:

```
Sub Gather_Values()
    Dim Rng As Range
    With Sheets("01").Range("A:AJ")
        Set Rng = .Find(What:="Data: ", _
                    After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Offset(0, 1)
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets.Add.Name = "New"
        Worksheets("New").Activate
        Range("A1").Select
                    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                    Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you include the code that you have written so far in your question?

Comment: It sounds that you could use the Find method on the Worksheet.Cells object - which returns all the cells of the Worksheet object. Does that make sense?

Comment: IAmDraged, It's the first time I use find method so I don't know much about it, I've tried to use on worksheet.cells() but it crashes, And I can't find the error I'll send the code that i wrote so far tomorrow cause I don't have on my pc only at my office

Comment: I did managed to do it with one cell using find without worksheet.cells but when I extend to all 3 it doesn't work

Comment: @RossMcConeghy i've updated with the code i did so far, this one works for one cell, i don't know how to extend it to find and copy all 3, and do repeat that same operation for all cases in the workbook, sometimes it happens 2 or 3 times in the same sheet

Comment: And the sheets name are random

Comment: If it happens more than one time in a single sheet you will need to know what pattern it will always come in or some rule for figuring out which set of values should be considered to be a single case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This subroutine will collate the 3 values for a single sheet named "01", searching the UsedRange of that sheet:

```
Sub Gather_Values()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Sht As Worksheet

    'create new worksheet, name it "New"
    Set Sht = Sheets.Add
    Sht.Name = "New"
    'set column titles in the new sheet
    Sht.Range("B1").Value = "Data"
    Sht.Range("C1").Value = "N°"
    Sht.Range("D1").Value = "Rodovia"

    'search the entire UsedRange of sheet 01
    With Sheets("01").UsedRange
        Set Rng = .Find(What:="Data: ", _
                    After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Offset(0, 1)
        Sht.Range("B2").Value = Rng.Value 'put value from the Find into B column of new sheet

        Set Rng = .Find(What:="N°", _
                    After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Offset(0, 1)
        Sht.Range("C2").Value = Rng.Value 'put value from the Find into C column of new sheet

        Set Rng = .Find(What:="Rodovia:", _
                    After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Offset(0, 1)
        Sht.Range("D2").Value = Rng.Value 'put value from the Find into D column of new sheet
    End With
End Sub
```

If the values appear more than once on a single sheet you will need to determine either what ranges of cells will always contain separate records or come up with a different way of parsing the data to make sure the values you find in sequence are of the same "case" or "record".

It would be helpful to see a sampling of the raw data that you are parsing to see if there is a better way to collate it than using Find(). It would be best to see an instance where there is more than one "case" in the raw data.

Comment: Actually that answer was pretty much what i needed, now i only have to apply a loop do it on all sheets and another macro i have to do it on all files in a folder, but i can handle it from here, thx a lot @RossMcConeghy =]